# Fastest way to increment a field in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose I have a MySQL table that keeps the page visit count and I want to keep track of total number of page visits for each user. Here's the SQL for incrementing the field:

```
UPDATE visits  
  SET visits = visits + 1  
  WHERE user_id = 12
```

It's pretty simple but I wonder whether there's a faster way to achieve this. I mean if I have a lot of visitors (ideally millions of users per day), is this method enough or I should use an alternative method. Thanks.

Comment: fastest way is through mySQL itself which generally your doing through your query currently. Any other alternative I could think of off the top of my head would require pulling the data out, altering it with php then putting the data back. Which is redundant if all you need to do is incriment a column when you can do it via your query.

Comment: Stick with it. If your user_id is a primary key (ideally an auto_increment), you are on the right track. You'll have statements way slower you have to worry about when thinking about 1 mio. users (not to mention the pageviews and therefor queries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an index on `user_id` this will be pretty fast. I doubt you'll be able to achieve a (noticeably) faster result using any other means. You will likely run into other performance / server issues with millions of users than this query (some call this "micro-optimization")

Comment: These types of queries on high-read sites can actually be quite devastating, especially on MyISAM... tossing into a secondary storage area and batching updates does help a lot.

Comment: @AdrianSchneider - What data draws you to that (subjective) conclusion?

Comment: Personal experience dealing with fairly high traffic sites.  With table-level locking, each update locks the table for a split second.  If this is always happening non-stop, the table is continuously locking every second.  It's much better on row-level locking obviously, but still something I like to avoid.  Not an issue for low traffic sites.

Comment: So table locking is the hindrance, and is alleviated with InnoDB?

Comment: Yes.  Inserting into another table alleviates this, versus updates which cause locking.

Comment: A few things have been mentioned here. So to add more to the question, what solution you think is the best for a web site that has a lot of visitors (like facebook)? To explain more, suppose something like the "like" table of facebook. I suppose each second there are hundreds of hits on the "like" link on facebook. I'm curious about those kind of solutions.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: they're using a lot (when I say a lot I mean a lot (40k+) of servers for this. I bet that the table is somehow partritioned.

Comment: Facebook is a special case, as they use HipHop for PHP and memcached to increase the scalability of their application.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and the comments. I learned a lot from these.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will be significant faster, but one thing you can do is stack their visits   and update their clicks count once per minute by cron job. Just be sure that `user_id` is indexed

Comment: Only prob with this is cache is volatile, so if the key/value pair is lost he will lose his visits count.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: it was just an example

Comment: +1 You could also have the app update the database every 1000th time it increments the memcached key.  If memcached crashes, update the visits in the database by RAND()*1000.

Comment: haha great solution! just update it by RAND()*1000 by the end of the day and don't bother with caching at all :)

Comment: @BillKarwin: hmm, that's not a good solution, I think. I have removed memcached as a solution, because it tends to crash

Comment: Well, the OP said he wants it fast, he didn't say he wanted it accurate. :)

Comment: @BillKarwin I didn't think it was necessary to mention accurate but to clarify it, I would have to say, I want it accurate AND fast.

Answer (score 0):

With an index on `visits` this could be pretty slow.
Though I'd advise to leave it as is, until you get at least 10 000 users.
As you will have to rewrite your code several times till then anyway.

Comment: Suppose you have 10 000 users.  What would you suggest as the solution then?

Comment: it depends on the use of such a quite useless number. For starter, I wouldn't bother with such a silly counter at all, but rather use either Google counter or implement some log analyser. But as you are expecting a database-wise solution, I'd make this field non-indexed and implement some offline stats aggregator to get the numbers. With 10K visitors a day it's still quite unnecessary though.

Comment: Thanks. Well, first of all, I've simplified my need with this "silly" code. In practice I'm not using this code, just an example for these types of questions. 2nd of all, could you please explain more about the Google counter? I'd like to know more about it. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori it's Google Analytics I mean. A powerful tool to count visits.